# Word to describe sci-fi vibe

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a word to describe a sci-fi, high tech vibe-- Imagine a server room with all the lights on and a dark atmosphere, or a glowing blue light on a glass floor.

**Example sentence:**

They stood on the ______ floor of the chamber, ready to travel to the West.

Thank you

Comment: Why not use _vibe_? It appears to mean whatever one wants it to mean. _They stood on the vibe floor of the chamber, ready to travel to the West._

Comment: I think the two examples you quoted outside of your example sentence, are quite different, so it will be hard to find a word that matches both. Here are some ideas that might help. http://www.dailywritingtips.com/36-adjectives-describing-light/. In terms of a sci-fi specific idea, you might use 'futuristic' but this doesn't really convey any information about lights as per your examples in the first paragraph, or the sense of eeriness in the server room example.

Comment: Are you looking for other-worldly or eerie?

Comment: How is this not a homework question, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Futuristic" would work well in your sentence. Otherwise the room might be described as "high-tech" or "space-age", although neither of those are quite one word.

Part of the reader's understanding of the room will be informed by the wider setting and context of the novel, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Take your time and explain it. There's nothing wrong with a sentence like

> They stood on the glass floor of the emotionless chamber. From beneath they could see a myriad of blinking lights. And even though no one knew what any of these lights did, they all decided to head west.